# Comparing values in a jagged array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, multidimensional-array

What I want to achieve is to compare the index values. arr1val1 and arr2val1, then arr1val2 and arr2val2, then so on and so forth provided that they have the same number of indexes. Lastly a message box that will prompt if a mismatch is detected in any of the compared indexes regardless of how many mismatches. So far I have this code.

```
 Dim str()() As String = _
        New String()() {New String() {"arr1val1", "arr1val2"}, New String() {"arr2val1", "arr2val2"}}

    For Each arstr As String() In str
        For Each strElement As String In arstr

        Next
    Next
```

Comment: So will the outer array always contain two inner arrays or is the number of inner arrays arbitrary?  If it's arbitrary, are you saying that you want to compare every inner array to every other one?  What exactly defines a mismatch?  Is it just different values at the same index in two inner arrays?  What is supposed to happen if two inner arrays don't have the same number of elements?

Comment: The outer array always contain two inner arrays. Two different values at the same index. Number of array elements are fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

```
Dim mismatchFound = False

For i = 0 To str(0).GetUpperBound(0)
    If str(0)(i) <> str(1)(i) Then
        mismatchFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The succinct way, i.e. using LINQ:

```
Dim mismatchFound = Enumerable.Range(0, str(0).Length).
                               Any(Function(i) str(0)(i) <> str(1)(i))
```

Comment: You said that the outer array always contains two inner arrays. If that is the case then you're already good to go because nowhere have I hard-coded the number of elements in the inner arrays. Are you now saying that that's not the case?

Comment: Sorry for that I'd just confused myself. Thank you for the solution!